# Using a context manager with a coroutine

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, coroutine

This code does not work

```
from contextlib import contextmanager                                                     
import tornado.ioloop                                                                     
import tornado.web                                                                        
from tornado import gen                                                                   
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient                                            


@contextmanager                                                                           
def hello():                                                                              
    print("hello in")                                                                     
    yield                                                                                 
    print("hello out")                                                                    


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):                                            
    @gen.coroutine                                                                        
    def get(self):                                                                        
        client = AsyncHTTPClient()                                                        
        with hello():                                                                     
            result = yield client.fetch("http://localhost")                               
        return "Hello "+str(result)                                                       

app = tornado.web.Application([('/', MainHandler)])                                       
app.listen(12345)                                                                         
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

And the reason why it doesn't work is that the context manager yielding and the coroutine yielding are incompatible in their behavior.

Do you confirm that the only way to achieve this is to use a `try finally` (particularly annoying if the context manager code must be used in many places). Maybe there's a subtle trick I don't know about? Googling did not help.

**edit**

This is the output I get

```
(venv) sborini@Mac-34363bd19f52:tornado$ python test.py 
hello in
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception GET / (::1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:12345', method='GET', uri='/', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1', headers={'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Host': 'localhost:12345', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sborini/Work/Experiments/tornado/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1445, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/Users/sborini/Work/Experiments/tornado/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/sborini/Work/Experiments/tornado/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/Users/sborini/Work/Experiments/tornado/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1014, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "test.py", line 20, in get
    result = yield client.fetch("http://localhost")
  File "/Users/sborini/Work/Experiments/tornado/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1008, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/sborini/Work/Experiments/tornado/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET / (::1) 5.04ms
```

The point is that I never get the `hello out` message. I would expect that, once `fetch` spawns the future and the future errors, I return back to the yield point, get the exception, and leave the context, triggering the `print('hello out')`.

Note that I do get hello out if I just do a `try: finally:` around the `yield`

Comment: Presumably this is because you're making something with `__enter__` and `__exit__` not `__aenter__` and `__aexit__`.

Comment: I'm not using async. I'm still on python 3.4 with vanilla tornado. @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of the code is correct, and it's fine to mix context managers and coroutines this way. The `@contextmanager` and `@coroutine` decorators each assign their own meanings to `yield` within their decorated functions, but they remain independent.

As written, this code will print "hello in" and "hello out" if the fetch to `http://localhost` succeeds (or if you change it to point to a server that works), but it won't print "hello out" if the fetch raises an exception. To do that, you need to use a `try/finally` in your decorator:

```
@contextmanager
def hello():                                                                              
    print("hello in")                                                                     
    try:
        yield                                                                                 
    finally:
        print("hello out")
```

One other error in this code is that you're returning a value from `get()`. The return value of `get()` is ignored; in Tornado to produce output you must call `self.write()` (or `finish()` or `render()`).

Comment: Correct for the observation. However the point is that I never see `hello out`

Comment: Amended the post for clarity.

Comment: On a side note, I am surprised that it doesn't. I don't see an immediate reason why it should not and I agree with your observation. But I can't make it work for some reason, and I can't understand why.

Comment: The error you get is because it cannot connect to localhost on port 80. The code is working (after Ben's note). Since `yield fetch` raises all HTTPErrors and your code doesn't handle that - the result is 500

Comment: @kwarunek I know that. It's not the point. The point is that I never see hello out, and I suspect that the reason is that the exception is dispatched to the yield in the context manager, and never reaches the coroutine

Comment: @kwarunek my use case expects the host not to be reachable.

Comment: because `contextmanager` is not `try/except`, the exception bubbles

Comment: Updated my answer. You need to use try/finally in the decorator to handle errors.

Comment: @BenDarnell excellent point. I thought that if you had an exception in a context manager declared that way, the part after the yield was going to be executed no matter what, because it's equivalent to the ``__exit__``

Comment: @BenDarnell thank you for your answer. By the say, I see you are lead developer of tornado. Thanks for it. It's really pleasant to use.

Answer (score 2):

This is a mechanic of `contextlib.contextmanager`, when an exception is raised inside the `with` block that error is thrown into `hello` so that it has access to the exception details and is given a change to suppress it (like a true context manager) for example:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager                                                     

@contextmanager                                                                           
def hello():                                                                              
    print("hello in")
    try:
        yield
    except:
        print("an exception was thrown into the generator! exit code would not have been run!")
        raise #commenting this out would suppress the original error which __exit__ can do by returning True
    finally:
        print("hello out")                                                                    


def get():                                                       
    with hello():                                                                     
        result = yield "VALUE"                              
    return "Hello "+str(result)                                                       

gen = get()
next(gen)
gen.throw(TypeError)
```

the output of this code example is:

```
hello in
an exception was thrown into the generator! exit code would not have been run!
hello out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py", line 24, in <module>
    gen.throw(TypeError)
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py", line 19, in get
    result = yield "VALUE"
TypeError
```

For this reason I'd recommend using a simple context class instead of using `contextlib.contextmanager` since the scematics will be easier with explicit `__enter__` and `__exit__`:

```
class hello:
    def __enter__(self):
        print("hello in")
    def __exit__(self,*args):
        print("hello out")
```

This way you are **guaranteed** that the exit code will run at the end of the `with` block.